# Are speculative questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

When [When will Windows Phone 8 be released?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/605/when-will-windows-phone-8-be-released) 
 was asked, it made me wonder if speculative questions should be off topic.

On the [Android StackExchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq), they specifically made questions like *When will X be available in my country*, and *When will application Y be released* off topic. Should we do the same? [This is the thread](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/speculative-questions-what-to-do) I can find that explains why.

I feel like for the majority of them we can only speculate. For the few that we could give a solid answer on, It would be a one-liner:

> It was announced at X that availability would start on Y

Should we just make these off topic as well?

Comment: Maybe We can contact Androide.SE via Teacher's Lounge and try to do the same thing. I created a chat about news too: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3714/fresh-news

Answer (score 1):

They should be off topic. Even if it is non-speculative then it is likely to be too localised and/or become out-of-date very quickly.